# MySQL to MariaDB - INSERT INTO with WHERE NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have this query on one of my script working on mysql database and not in mariadb database.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (item1, item2) 
    SELECT 'A','B' 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT item1, item2
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE myTable.item1='A' AND myTable.item2='B') LIMIT 1;
```

It's insert value if this value doesnt exist.

Is it possible to have a kind of this query working on the both database (mariaDB and mysql) ?

Comment: try adding a from on the select, something among these lines:
INSERT INTO myTable (item1, item2)
SELECT 'A','B' FROM myTable 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT item1, item2
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE myTable.item1='A' AND myTable.item2='B') LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create inline view (1 column 1 value like dual in Oracle):

```
INSERT INTO myTable (item1, item2) 
    SELECT 'A','B' 
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS dummy) s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT item1, item2
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE myTable.item1='A' AND myTable.item2='B') LIMIT 1;

-- or use dual directly
INSERT INTO myTable (item1, item2) 
    SELECT 'A','B' 
    FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT item1, item2
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE myTable.item1='A' AND myTable.item2='B') LIMIT 1;
```

**[DBFiddle MySQL 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0de1789078d3a14b71a752ab997ca667)**

**[DBFiddle MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=0de1789078d3a14b71a752ab997ca667)**